# ROS build a package but can't run

Tags: ros, build, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,

I build a workspace folder which called jade_workspace in the home directory. In the jade_workspace folder, there are 3 files here which are the "setup.bash" , "setup.sh" , "setup.zsh", and I also create a folder here called sandbox.

In the sandbox, I want to create a package calls "beginner_tutorials", and I use the command as
"roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp" , after that, I use "rosmake beginner_tutorials" to build some data in this folder.

After that, because I run the example of "Creating a ROS Package" and "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)", and I can run the talker and listener successfully in the example. I copy the file of "talker","listener" and "CMakeLists.txt"
, "package.xml" to the jade_workspace's beginner_tutorials folder.

And after I source it and ran the talker, it shows the error as below:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/terry/jade_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223220/ros-build-a-package-but-can%27t-run/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like your workspace does not have the correct folder structure.

Part 4 on this page http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment tells you how to set up a workspace with the correct folder structure.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-29**:
Hello Ntckw, I followed the "rosbuild"part of part 4 of your link, I think my path is right, but it can't be executed,too. I put my terminal reply in the next

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-29**:\

1. terry@terry-All-Series:~$ source ~/jade_workspace/setup.bash
   2. terry@terry-All-Series:~$ cd ~/jade_workspace/sandboxterry
2. @terry-All-Series:~/jade_workspace/sandbox$ rospack find beginner_tutorials：
   /home/terry/jade_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-29**:
4. terry@terry-All-Series:~/jade_workspace/sandbox$ printenv | grep ROS
5. ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/jade/share/ros
6. ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/terry/jade_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks
7. ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
8. ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/terry/jade_workspace

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-29**:\

1. ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
2. ROS_DISTRO=jade
3. ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/jade/etc/ros

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-12-29**:
The sandbox folder is not part of the usual folder layout for a workspace (unless it is the name of a package that you have created, but that would be in the src folder). I would expect the setup files to be in folder called devel inside your workspace if initialising the workspace had run correctly

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-12-29**:
I just realised you are using rosbuild, I misread the title,sorry. Thats why you have a sandbox folder. Unless you need to use rosbuild for backwards compatibility with something it is more common to use catkin now.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-29**:
Now, I use the catkin instead of rosbuild. It is easier. But in any case, thank you.